# SharePoint 2010 - What is the Managed Property for "Enterprise Keywords" field?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have Pages libraries which have the Enterprise Keywords site column included. If I'm loading a page where the Enterprise Keywords column contains 'homepage', then I want to get the list of all other pages that have the same value in their Enterprise Keywords column.

I'm trying to write a KeyWordQuery for searching on the Taxonomy field for Enterprise Keywords. But I'm not sure which is the managed property for it. I find a crawled property called "TaxKeyword" but it is not mapped to any Managed Property.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the "Tags" mapped property you are looking for? I believe the "Tags" mapped propery will return values from the Enterprise Keywords column.